# Why Sum is not working with multiple case in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following mysql query for calculating sum of scores by  a student. The query execute successfully but output NULL under Scoring field.

```
Select regd, Subject, Section, Test_date,
SUM(t_scored+w_scored+f_scored+cce_scored) as Scoring
from
(SELECT regd, Subject, Section, Test_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam', 'Third Unit Exam')
THEN Mark_score
END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam', 'Third Unit Exam')
THEN Full_Mark
END)*25 AS t_scored,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam' 'Third Unit Exam')
THEN (Full_mark)
END) AS t_fm,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
THEN Mark_score
END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
THEN Full_Mark
END)*25 AS w_scored,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
THEN (Full_mark)
END) AS w_fm,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
THEN Mark_score
END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
THEN Full_Mark
END)*25 AS f_scored,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
THEN (Mark_score)
END) AS score_m,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
THEN Mark_score
END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
THEN Full_Mark
END)*25 AS cce_scored,

SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
THEN (Full_mark)
END) AS cce_fm
FROM kg2_exam 
WHERE regd='2275' AND Subject not in ('Music','Handwriting','Colouring'))t
group by Subject
```

As you can see from my code, I want to sum t_scored+w_scored+f_scored+cce_scored. But the code here only outputs NULL while there are values in some of the Mark_score and Full_Mark Fields. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
SUM(IF(Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam',Mark_score,0))
```

If you are sure, the subquery return valid results and there is no need to change, You can try to change  this

```
SUM(t_scored+w_scored+f_scored+cce_scored)
```

to this

```
SUM(IF(t_scored IS NULL, 0,t_scored)+IF(w_scored IS NULL, 0,w_scored)+IF(f_scored IS NULL, 0,f_scored)+IF(cce_scored IS NULL, 0,cce_scored))
```

There must be NULL somewhere so 45+NULL would be NULL

Comment: @Skriptajs The first part of the code SUM(t_score+... is the one that is not working.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to find from where the NULL values are.